# Remove space before and after special characters

Tags: java, string

I have a string,

```
String sample = "He won the International Rating Chess Tournament (IRCT ) which concluded on Dec. 22 at the Blue Sky Hotel , Canada";
```

I want to remove space (**if any**) left before characters ')' and ','. So the final output should be like,

```
He won the International Rating Chess Tournament (IRCT) which concluded on Dec. 22 at the Blue Sky Hotel, Canada
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Replace all " )" with ")", applied repeatedly until nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 7):

```
sample.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[),])", "");
```

i.e. Remove all whitespace `\s+` that is immediately followed by `(?=...)` any of the following characters `[),]`. Double-backslashes are for escaping. More info about regular expressions can be seen here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 4):

```
sample = sample.replaceAll(" ,", ",").replaceAll(" )", ")");
```

If you want to remove any number of spaces before `)` and `,`, you can use a regex :

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("\\s+,", ",").replaceAll("\\s+\\)", ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String sample = "He won the International Rating Chess Tournament (IRCT ) which concluded on Dec. 22 at the Blue Sky Hotel , Canada";
    sample=sample.replace(" )", ")");
    sample=sample.replace(" ,", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should remove the white spaces before and after -

`\s+(?=[-])|(?<=-)\s*`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.